# Python: How do I make a list that allows for individual inputs one by one

Tags: python, list

I want to make a list, set, or tuple that will allow a user to input a string, then once that's done they will input the next and the next. I have 4 inputs. I want it so the the first input shows up, and then only when the user has typed their answer, will the second input show up. Then finally, it will print the full list enumerated. Sorry if this is simple, I'm new to coding.

```py
empty_list = []
empty_list = list()

input = empty_list = print("What is your 1st period class? ")
input = empty_list = print("What is your 2nd period class? ")
input = empty_list = print("What is your 3rd period class? ")
input = empty_list = print("What is your online class? ")


class_list = []
empty_list = class_list

print(enumerate(class_list))
```

Comment: This is *probably* simple but your question is very unclear. The code you present doesn't work, and doesn't communicate what you actually want. How would a normal, syntactically valid `input()` statement not work? It doesn't proceed before the user provides input, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: ```empty_list = []``` next line ```x=input("What is your 1st period class?")``` next line ```empty_list.append(x)```

Answer (score 0):

One way using list comprehension:

```
msgs = ["What is your 1st period class? ",
        "What is your 2nd period class? ",
        "What is your 3rd period class? ",
        "What is your online class? ",]
class_list = [input(msg) for msg in msgs]
print(*enumerate(class_list))
```

Output:

```
# What is your 1st period class? A
# What is your 2nd period class? B
# What is your 3rd period class? C
# What is your online class? D

(0, 'A') (1, 'B') (2, 'C') (3, 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
empty_list = list()

answer = input("What is your 1st period class? ")
empty_list.append(answer)
answer = input("What is your 2nd period class? ")
empty_list.append(answer)
answer = input("What is your 3rd period class? ")
empty_list.append(answer)
answer = input("What is your online class? ")
empty_list.append(answer)

for item in empty_list:

    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are looking for the append function on lists.

```
empty_list = []

empty_list.append(input("What is your 1st period class? "))
empty_list.append(input("What is your 2nd period class? "))
empty_list.append(input("What is your 3rd period class? "))
empty_list.append(input("What is your online class? "))

for i in empty_list:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
empty_list = []

input1 = input("What is your 1st period class? ")
empty_list.append(input1)
input2 = input("What is your 2nd period class? ")
empty_list.append(input2)
input3 = input("What is your 3rd period class? ")
empty_list.append(input3)
input4 = input("What is your online class? ")
empty_list.append(input4)
```

For Enumeration of list

```
print (list(enumerate(empty_list)))
```